# getting an error when dependency injection in console app with autofac

Tags: c#, console-application, autofac, jobs

This question previously asked actually

1. [Using Autofac to inject a dependency into the Main entry point in a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741131/using-autofac-to-inject-a-dependency-into-the-main-entry-point-in-a-console-app)
2. [Correct use of Autofac in C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413055/correct-use-of-autofac-in-c-sharp-console-application/48413665#48413665)

Just want to call the non-static method from my main static method in the console app

So I followed the above articles, built in this way

```
namespace SampleConsoleApp
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class Program
    {
        private ISampleService _oSampleService;
        
        private static IContainer CompositionRoot()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<SampleInitialize>();
            builder.RegisterType<SampleService>().As<ISampleService>();
            return builder.Build();
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CompositionRoot().Resolve<SampleInitialize>().Run_Auto();
        }
    }
}

namespace SampleConsoleApp
{
    public class SampleInitialize
    {
  
        private ISampleService _oSampleService;

        public SampleInitialize(ISampleService oSampleService)
        {
            _oSampleService = oSampleService;
        }

        public void Run_Auto()
        {
           var _list = _oSampleService.GetList();
        }
    }
}

namespace SampleConsoleApp
{
    public class SampleService : ISampleService
    {
        public SampleService(IContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }
        
        public List<String> GetList()
        {
            var _list = new List<String>();
            
            ....
         
            return _list;
        }
    }
    
}

namespace SampleConsoleApp
{
    public interface ISampleService
    {
        List<String> GetList();
    }   
}
```

but I'm getting an error once this launch as following

> None of the constructors found with
> 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on  type
> 'SampleConsoleApp.SampleInitialize' can be invoked with the available
> services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter
> 'SampleConsoleApp.SampleService.ISampleService oSampleService'  of
> constructor 'Void .ctor(SampleConsoleApp.ISampleService)'.

Comment: The error seems to be pointing to the inability to create SampleService because IContext cannot be resolved. A class implementing IContext needs to be registered.

Comment: @hocho so you meant, this class `public class SampleDbContext : DbContext, IContext` ? can I know where it should register?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned from @hocho you need to register IContext.

```
    private static IContainer CompositionRoot()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<SampleInitialize>();
        builder.RegisterType<SampleService>().As<ISampleService>();
        builder.RegisterType<SampleDbContext>().As<IContext>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Afterwards you need to register everything needed by SampleDbContext constructor as well.

Comment: after register In this context class still getting the same error :(

Comment: I found the reason and way to achieve this, will share here once I composed an article, thanks for your support